# Direct bandgap semiconductor reaction to heat. Produce light?

Tags: photons, solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics, light-emitting-diodes

In an indirect bandgap semiconductor if you apply heat the number of free electrons increases, conductivity increases, and the bandgap decreases.

In a direct bandgap semiconductor is there any photons emitted from recombination due to the heat?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you should note that the bandgap is negligibly affected by temperature. The rise in carrier concentration is due solely electrons having higher kinetic energy.

Emission of photons due to heat does not occur. Think about it this way, even at room temperature of ~300K, the semiconductor has technically been heated since it is not at absolute zero. But there is no photon emission.

If you raise the temperature above 300K, the same principle applies. The semiconductor will reach thermal equilibrium at the new temperature and any radiative recombination will just excite another electron rather than being emitted (so technically photon may be emitted but it isn't visible).

Visible photon emission only occurs when there are excess carriers. As recombination rate will exceed generation rate when excess carriers are present, the photons emitted near the surface of the semiconductor sample can make it out.